# EMGU CV High resolution Image need to save

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need to save high Resolution image from a camera, iam getting the image but its quality is so poor. in picture box i have set 1288x1024, need same resolution on saving the picture !!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what this necessarily has to do with Emgu/C#, but if you want to use Emgu to resize your image, you can try the CvInvoke.Resize method, [detailed here](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.0/document/html/c9c13b1e-4f15-31ea-9d40-4a76d5bee079.htm).

```
public static void Resize(
    IInputArray src,
    IOutputArray dst,
    Size dsize,
    double fx = 0,
    double fy = 0,
    Inter interpolation = Inter.Linear
)
```